# How do i load dynamic scripts in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

Angular: 7.1.4
I was trying to fix the problem of loading the scripts because I was giving the error `Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property` Responsive 'of undefined`. I discovered a possible solution that was to create a service to load the scripts dynamically. I followed the tutorial and did everything for it to work, but it is not working.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

interface Scripts {
  name: string;
  src: string;
}

export const ScriptStore: Scripts[] = [
  { name: 'jquery', src: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' },
  { name: 'tables', src: '../../../assets/dashboard/js/tables.js' },
  { name: 'widgets', src: '../../../assets/dashboard/js/widgets.js' },
  { name: 'charts', src: '../../../assets/dashboard/js/charts.js' },
  { name: 'theme.min', src: '../../../assets/dashboard/dist/js/theme.min.js'}
];

declare var document: any;

@Injectable()
export class DynamicScriptLoaderService {

  private scripts: any = {};

  constructor() {
    ScriptStore.forEach((script: any) => {
      this.scripts[script.name] = {
        loaded: false,
        src: script.src
      };
    });
  }

  load(...scripts: string[]) {
    const promises: any[] = [];
    scripts.forEach((script) => promises.push(this.loadScript(script)));
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }

  loadScript(name: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.scripts[name].loaded) {
        //load script
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
        if (script.readyState) {  //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                    resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
                }
            };
        } else {  //Others
            script.onload = () => {
                this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
            };
        }
        script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({script: name, loaded: false, status: 'Loaded'});
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      } else {
        resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Already Loaded' });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then, i try to call this service on init of the component to load the scripts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScripts();
  }

  private loadScripts() {
    // You can load multiple scripts by just providing the key as argument into load method of the service
    this.dynamicScriptLoader.load(
      'jquery',
      'tables',
      'widgets',
      'charts',
      'theme.min'
      )
      .then(data => {
        console.log('scripts loaded')
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

The errors that I get when I use this service are several, in addition to continuing with the same error as before, others appear as, `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, `Uncaught ReferenceError: c3 is not defined` from file charts, and others like that. I'm probably making some wrong call from this service, as I've seen some tutorials that look good.

Comment: You can also use angular.json to specify external scripts to be loaded in it's: "scripts" section.

Comment: Yeah, i alredy try to load the these scripts in angular.json, but the `Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property' Responsive 'of undefined` continues..

Comment: What is the code accessing the `Responsive` property?

Comment: Also your `theme.min` script refers to `charts.js`, which is already referenced

Comment: This issue of `theme.min` is fixed. `Responsive` property is used in `responsive.bootstrap4.min.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. i re-code many of my html, and probably i was calling some script js two times..